# htaccess redirects while moving to multisite under subdomain with tld change

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a Wordpress website that is ranking well on www.domain.fr. I need to add english language. Fo this purpose I plan to convert the single site to WP multisite and I'd like to set www.domain.com for EN and move current FR language from www.domain.fr to fr.domain.com.

So my first aim is to redirect all trafic for all pages from https://www.domain.fr/* to https://fr.domain.com/*

Here is my htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.fr$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://fr.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

While testing, it works fine for domain, says www.domain.fr is well redirect to fr.domain.com

But when I try www.domain.fr/any-page/ it does not work says server return www.domain.fr/a-page/ instead of fr.domain.com/a-page/

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You need to place the redirection _before_ the internal rewriting rules. So further up in the distributed configuration file.

Comment: @arkascha Why not write that as an answer, after all, that IS the answer. (?)

Comment: @arkascha Thanks a lot

Comment: @MrWhite I am sure that Greg would have found that out without my help pretty fast...

Answer (score 1):

As @arkascha commented above I need to place the redirection before the internal rewriting rules.